# How to generate a DropDownListFor with multiple columns

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, html.dropdownlistfor

In a .cshtml razor view,

This works:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
  m => m.PersonId, //bound value
  new SelectList(Model.Persons, "PersonId", "FirstName" , 0), //list
  " -- Select A Person -- " //default
)
```

However, `Model.Persons`, in addition to containing `Model.Persons.PersonId` and `Model.Persons.FirstName`, also contains `Model.Persons.LastName`.

How can I have the last name also show up in the select list as another column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a property "Full Name" that is a ready only property that returns both of those properties. You can then use that in place of "FirstName"

Comment: This was a simple example, but you are saying that I should include a string in my viewmodel for each row display in the dropdownlist? So far from what I have seen that is what others have suggested as well (i.e. DisplayText = "{0} | {1} | ... etc", field1, field2)

Comment: ya - the view model should contain everything that needs to be displayed. Personally I use ViewModels (not 'domain models' or 'entities') that contain everything to be shown as its either a superset or a subset of an entity. I also include properties like the above, in addition IEnumerable<SelectListItems> right in the model so everything is ready to go.

Comment: That is pretty much what I ended up doing. I made a class named genericitems which has `int id` and `string display`. In my viewmodels I just include a `List<genericitems> SomeName` type of deal. And I also include a starting index value and a top label for the list in the view model.